# Answer coming wrong for some test cases

Tags: java, string

Given two strings A and B of lowercase letters, return true if and only if we can swap two letters in A so that the result equals B.For test case below answer is coming wrong.

```
Input:
"aaaaaaabc"
"aaaaaaacb"
```

```
class Solution {
    public boolean buddyStrings(String A, String B)
    {
        int count=0,index=0;
        int a[] = new int[A.length()];
        if( A.length()!=B.length() )
            return false;
        if( A.equals(B) )
        {
            for(int i=0; i<A.length() ;i++)
            {
                if( A.charAt(0)==A.charAt(i) )
                    count++;
            }
            return( count==A.length() );
        }

        for(int i=0; i<A.length(); i++)
        {
            if(A.charAt(i) ! = B.charAt(i))
                a[index++] = i;
        }
         if( a.length==2 )
        {
            if(A.charAt(a[0])==B.charAt(a[1]) && A.charAt(a[1])==B.charAt(a[0]))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        } 
        else
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close. Below is my solution to the problem, namely: *return true if and only if we can swap two letters in A so that the result equals B* Explanations after the code.

```
public boolean buddyStrings(String s1, String s2) {
    boolean result = false;
    if (s1 != null  &&  s2 != null) {
        char[] letters1 = s1.toCharArray();
        char[] letters2 = s2.toCharArray();
        if (letters1.length == letters2.length  &&  letters1.length > 1) {
            int[] indices = new int[2];
            int index = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < letters1.length; i++) {
                if (letters1[i] != letters2[i]) {
                    if (index < 2) {
                        indices[index++] = i;
                    }
                    else {
                        index++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (index == 2) {
                result = letters1[indices[0]] == letters2[indices[1]];
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Firstly, as in your code, the lengths of both strings must be equal and the lengths should be more than 1 (one), since you can't swap two letters in a string when the string contains only one letter.

Now we check corresponding letters in each string and we save the indices of corresponding letters that are different. For your test strings, for example, the indices would be 7 and 8. There must be precisely two such indices. Hence I save the indices in an int array of size 2.

After checking all the letters, there must be precisely two letters that are different. All that's left is to check that if we swap the two letters, the two strings will be identical.

Comment: The output should be true if I give input Strings as .. "aa" and "aa" ..as swaping the characers of s1 gives me s2.

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code is the problem.

```java
if( A.equals(B) )
        {
            for(int i=0; i<A.length() ;i++)
            {
                if( A.charAt(0)==A.charAt(i) )
                    count++;
            }
            return( count==A.length() );
        }
```

Consider a case where A = B = "abcdefga".

According to your code, `i` takes up values from 0 to 7. The condition is only satisfied once, i.e. when `i = 7`, so count is equal to 1 when the loop is terminated. In your `return` statement, `count == A.length()` returns `false` because 1 =/= 7.

Comment: What condition should I put then for this case? For input 1)"aab" answer should be true and for 2)"abb" answer should be false.